# How to restore the default html output destination in SAS?

Tags: sas

This must be so simple, but I can't find it:

How do you restore the default output destination in SAS 9.3?

Unlike 9.2, that is HTML.

In other words, which commands voids this statement.

```
ods html close;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn HTML back on with

ODS HTML;

but there are probably other options you need...like a filename

ODS html file="My File.htm";

[ODS HTML](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi29/172-29.pdf)